# List Control delete item by specific column

Tags: c++, winapi, listcontrol

How Can I delete specific item with only know specific column ?

Comment: How Can I answer question with only know nothing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Found an answer ..

```
LVITEM lvi;
ZeroMemory(&lvi, sizeof(LVITEM));
lvi.pszText = "SomeText";
lvi.iSubItem = 1;
SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hWindow, IDC_LIST_USERS), LVM_GETITEM, 0, (LPARAM)(&lvi));
SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hWindow, IDC_LIST_USERS) , LVM_DELETEITEM, lvi.iItem, 0);
```